# Hue value range in opencv

Tags: opencv

It is noted OpenCV has a hue value range of [0 179] ([Detect red circles in an image using OpenCV](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/detect-red-circles-image-using-opencv/)) (please correct me if the statement is not right). Here below is my function for obtaining the hue values of Mat image:

```
Mat MainWindow::getHue(const Mat &src)
{
    Mat bgr32; //CV_32FC3
    src.convertTo(bgr32,CV_32FC3,1/255.0);

    Mat hsv(bgr32.size(), CV_32FC3);
    cvtColor(bgr32,hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Mat hue(hsv.size(), CV_32FC1);
    Mat sat(hsv.size(), CV_32FC1);
    Mat val(hsv.size(), CV_32FC1);
    Mat out[] = {hue,sat,val};
    split(hsv,out);

    return hue;
}
```

The generated hue value that way is actually in the range of [0, 360]. What is the problem? I use `opencv3.4.5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_hsv) is the documentation for the RGB to HSV conversion.

Since the range of `uchar` is [0,255], you cannot store the entire hue range. Therefore, opencv decided to use a trick. For this type of matrices, divide the hue by 2. However, this trick is only used for `uchar` matrices. Floating point matrices, which can store the entire hue range, do not have to resort to this.

To see the trick in action, simply use a `uchar` matrix:

```
Mat MainWindow::getHue(const Mat &src)
{

    Mat hsv(src.size(), CV_8UC3);
    cvtColor(src,hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Mat hue(hsv.size(), CV_8UC1);
    Mat sat(hsv.size(), CV_8UC1);
    Mat val(hsv.size(), CV_8UC1);
    Mat out[] = {hue,sat,val};
    split(hsv,out);

    return hue;
}
```

Now `hue` is in the range [0, 180].